# Login to Hotmail account with httpclient in java

Tags: java, httpclient, http-post, hotmail

I want to login to hotmail account with httpclient in java. Following is my code. Please note that I found a list of parameters to be passed with post method, with the help of "tamper data" add on in firefox. It seems that hotmail uses javascript and therefore I could not fetch values of few parameters to be passed with post method. Can anybody please help me out here ?It is taking me to the same page. and Status code returned by post method is 200 OK which means it's not redirecting either.

I would really appreciate any help !

Thanks.

Ragini

```
public void executeParser(String website_url, String emailid,String password) throws Exception
{
    String ppft=null;
    client.getParams().setParameter(HttpMethodParams.USER_AGENT,
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401 Firefox/8.0 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)");

    client.getParams().setCookiePolicy(org.apache.http.client.params.CookiePolicy.BROWSER_COMPATIBILITY);

    GetMethod get_siteurl = new GetMethod(website_url);
    client.executeMethod(get_siteurl);
    is = get_siteurl.getResponseBodyAsStream();
    output = StringFormat.convertStreamToString(is); 
    //System.out.println(output);
    get_siteurl.releaseConnection();

    Parser parser= new Parser(output);
    NodeList nodelist1 = parser.parse(null);
    NodeList list1 = nodelist1.extractAllNodesThatMatch(inputfilter , true);
    for(int i=0;i<list1.size();i++)
    {
        Node n=list1.elementAt(i);
        if(n.getText().contains("PPFT"))
        {
          ppft=n.getText();
          String s[]=ppft.split("value=");
          ppft=s[1];
          ppft=ppft.replaceAll("\"","");
          ppft=ppft.replaceAll("/","");
          //System.out.println(ppft);
          break;
        }

    }

    //POST PARAMETERS TO LOGIN TO HOTMAIL ACCOUNT
    PostMethod post_uname_pwd = new PostMethod("https://login.live.com/ppsecure/post.srf");

    post_uname_pwd.getParams().setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.BROWSER_COMPATIBILITY);

    NameValuePair userid =   new NameValuePair("login",emailid);
    NameValuePair pwd = new NameValuePair("passwd", password);
    NameValuePair type = new NameValuePair("type","11" );
    NameValuePair loginoptions = new NameValuePair("LoginOptions", "3");
    NameValuePair newuser = new NameValuePair("NewUser","1");
    NameValuePair mest = new NameValuePair("MEST", "");
    NameValuePair idsbho = new NameValuePair("idsbho", "1");
    NameValuePair pwdpad = new NameValuePair("PwdPad", "");
    NameValuePair PPFT = new NameValuePair("PPFT",ppft);
    NameValuePair sso = new NameValuePair("sso", "");
    NameValuePair i1 = new NameValuePair("i1", "");
    NameValuePair i2 = new NameValuePair("i2", "1");
    NameValuePair i4 = new NameValuePair("i4","");
    NameValuePair i12 = new NameValuePair("i12","1");
    NameValuePair i13 = new NameValuePair("i13","");
    NameValuePair i17 = new NameValuePair("i17", "");
    NameValuePair button = new NameValuePair("SI", "Sign in");

    NameValuePair[] data = {userid,pwd,type,loginoptions,newuser,mest,idsbho,pwdpad,PPFT,sso,i1,i2,i4,i12,i13,i17,button};

    //post_uname_pwd.getParams().setCookiePolicy(org.apache.http.client.params.CookiePolicy.BROWSER_COMPATIBILITY);
    post_uname_pwd.setRequestBody(data);
    client.executeMethod(post_uname_pwd);

    is = post_uname_pwd.getResponseBodyAsStream();
    output = StringFormat.convertStreamToString(is); 
    System.out.println(output);
    //post_uname_pwd.releaseConnection();

    int statuscode = post_uname_pwd.getStatusCode();
    post_uname_pwd.releaseConnection();
    System.out.println(statuscode);
    if ((statuscode == HttpStatus.SC_MOVED_TEMPORARILY) ||
            (statuscode == HttpStatus.SC_MOVED_PERMANENTLY) ||
            (statuscode == HttpStatus.SC_SEE_OTHER) ||
            (statuscode == HttpStatus.SC_TEMPORARY_REDIRECT)) 
    {
        Header header = post_uname_pwd.getResponseHeader("Location");
        System.out.println("Header is : " + header.getValue());

        if (header != null) 
        {
            String newuri = header.getValue();

            //System.out.println("Redirect target after Post: " + newuri);
            GetMethod redirect = new GetMethod(newuri);
            client.executeMethod(redirect);
            is = redirect.getResponseBodyAsStream();
            output = StringFormat.convertStreamToString(is); 
            System.out.println(output);
            redirect.releaseConnection();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hotmail?! Oh god, I forgot that even existed... Thanks for the trip down memory lane.

Comment: The parameters "type", "LoginOptions", "NewUser" are actually optional.

Answer (score 2):

Use HtmlUnit, it is the best way to achieve what you want.

You can get it from http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

I found out that only few parameters are needed to login to hotmail account. here is my Final code:

```
public void executeParser(String website_url, String emailid,String password) throws Exception
{
    //Website url is https://login.live.com/ppsecure/post.srf
    String ppft=null;
    client.getParams().setParameter(HttpMethodParams.USER_AGENT,
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401 Firefox/8.0 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)");

    client.getParams().setCookiePolicy(org.apache.http.client.params.CookiePolicy.BROWSER_COMPATIBILITY);

    GetMethod get_siteurl = new GetMethod(website_url);
    client.executeMethod(get_siteurl);
    is = get_siteurl.getResponseBodyAsStream();
    output = StringFormat.convertStreamToString(is); 
    get_siteurl.releaseConnection();

    Parser parser= new Parser(output);
    NodeList nodelist1 = parser.parse(null);
    NodeList list1 = nodelist1.extractAllNodesThatMatch(inputfilter , true);
    for(int i=0;i<list1.size();i++)
    {
        Node n=list1.elementAt(i);
        if(n.getText().contains("PPFT"))
        {
          ppft=n.getText();
          String s[]=ppft.split("value=");
          ppft=s[1];
          ppft=ppft.replaceAll("\"","");
          ppft=ppft.replaceAll("/","");
          break;
        }

    }

    //POST PARAMETERS TO LOGIN TO HOTMAIL ACCOUNT
    PostMethod postdata = new PostMethod("https://login.live.com/ppsecure/post.srf");

    postdata.getParams().setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.BROWSER_COMPATIBILITY);

    NameValuePair userid =   new NameValuePair("login",emailid);
    NameValuePair pwd = new NameValuePair("passwd", password);
    NameValuePair type = new NameValuePair("type","11" );
    NameValuePair loginoptions = new NameValuePair("LoginOptions", "3");
    NameValuePair newuser = new NameValuePair("NewUser","1");
    NameValuePair PPFT = new NameValuePair("PPFT",ppft);        
    //NameValuePair button = new NameValuePair("SI", "Sign in");

    NameValuePair[] data = {userid,pwd,type,loginoptions,newuser,PPFT};

    postdata.setRequestBody(data);
    client.executeMethod(postdata);

    is =postdata.getResponseBodyAsStream();
    output = StringFormat.convertStreamToString(is); 
    postdata.releaseConnection();

    int statuscode = postdata.getStatusCode();
    postdata.releaseConnection();

    if ((statuscode == HttpStatus.SC_MOVED_TEMPORARILY) ||
            (statuscode == HttpStatus.SC_MOVED_PERMANENTLY) ||
            (statuscode == HttpStatus.SC_SEE_OTHER) ||
            (statuscode == HttpStatus.SC_TEMPORARY_REDIRECT)) 
    {
        Header header = postdata.getResponseHeader("Location");
        if (header != null) 
        {
            String newuri = header.getValue();
            GetMethod redirect = new GetMethod(newuri);
            client.executeMethod(redirect);
            redirect.releaseConnection();
        }
    }

    GetMethod get = new GetMethod("http://mail.live.com/default.aspx");
    get.setFollowRedirects(true);
    client.executeMethod(get);
    is = get.getResponseBodyAsStream();
    output = StringFormat.convertStreamToString(is); 
    System.out.println("This is the final page after login: "+ output);

}
```

}